# Can't read framework

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

> error: unable to read module map contents from 'Target Support Files/Bolts/Bolts.modulemap': Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Bolts.modulemap” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/chrisgerton/Desktop/impro21/Pods/Target Support Files/Bolts/Bolts.modulemap, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8c685a9e50 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

I've been struggling with this for a few days now and I could use some guidance.

Comment: After you ran `pod install`, did you open the workspace or the original Xcode file for your project?

Comment: @Adrian I opened the workspace. It has been working fine until a few days ago.

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried removing the CocoaPod and reinstalling it or doing a `pod update`?

Comment: @Adrian Yes I did both and still nothing.

Comment: @Adrian I did the pod update and had no changes, but I restarted my computer and it worked.